# invalid use of undefined type ‘struct Square’?

Tags: c

I am making a program that solves a sudoku game, but I received an error from my compiler.

```
error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct Square’
   30 |         if(box->squares[x]->possible[number-1] == 0){
                                  ^~
```

the function is:

```
int updateBoxes(Square *** sudoku, int row, int column){
    int x;
    int number = sudoku[row][column]->number;
    Box * box;
    box = sudoku[row][column]->box;

    for(x = 0; x < SIZE_ROWS; x++){
        if(box->squares[x]->possible[number-1] == 0){
            box->squares[x]->solvable--;
            box->squares[x]->possible[number-1] = 1;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

the error also aplies to the next two lines.

the definitions of `Square` and `Box` are:

```
typedef struct box
{
    struct Square ** squares;  /* array of Squares */
    int numbers;
    int possible[9];
    int solvable;
    struct Box * next;
} Box;

/* square is a single number in the board */
typedef struct square
{
    int number;     
    int possible[9];
    /*
       the array is only made of 0 and 1
       each index corresponds to a number: ex: index 4 == number 5 ...
       1 tells me that 5 cannot go into this scare
       0 tells me that 5 can go into this scare
    */
    int solvable;   /* will be subtracted 1 each time and when it is 1 it's because is solvable */
    Box * box;      /* tells me the corresponding box */
    int row;
    int column;
} Square;
```

I am following a tutorial on youtube and the guy doesn't get the error that I get, the youtube video is:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CnzrCBLCDhc&t=1326s

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. The problem is in the details and you may have omitted important ones in your excerpts.

Comment: The `struct Square` seems to be not visible from the code. Possibly caused by a missing `#include`.

Comment: Look VERY carefully at what is in Capitalised and what is lowercase. Even in the error report... Should be same problem with Box/box... And, because each type seems to want to point to the other, you're gonna need "forward declaration" of one of them...

Comment: As your answer observes, you appear to be confusing your struct *tags* and the typedef *aliases* you are declaring for your types.  Note well that you can define structure types without using `typedef`, and I generally recommend doing so.  In fact, `typedef` is entirely a syntactic sugar feature -- it doesn't let you do anything that you couldn't do without.  Or maybe syntactic saccharine, because there are relatively few things you can do with it that actually make your code clearer or easier to maintain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've used `struct Square` where you should have used `struct square` in the `Box` definition. Corrected:

```c
typedef struct box {
    struct square** squares; /* array of Squares */
//         ^
    int numbers;
    int possible[9];
    int solvable;
    struct box* next; // box, not Box
} Box;
```

Another option is to `typedef` `Square` before `Box` and use `Square` in `Box`:

```c
typedef struct square Square;
typedef struct box Box;
struct box {
    Square** squares; /* array of Squares */
    int numbers;
    int possible[9];
    int solvable;
    Box* next;
};
```

Note that there is nothing called `struct Square` after these definitions. There is `struct square` and `Square`.

Comment: Looks like member `struct Box* next;` should be giving the compiler heartburn, too...

Comment: @Fe2O3 _"heartburn"_ :-) Yes, that seems likely. I added an edit for that too.

Comment: thank you very much, it solved my problem. it's my first time using stack overflow, it's good to see that there are good people to help out. Thank you.